# Can Hanzo's Ultimate Arrow kill? (Not his DragonStrike)

Tags: overwatch

When Hanzo activates his ultimate he fires an arrow with the range of 5 meters, in the case that an enemy hero goes in front of him will it damage/kill them?

if he kill them what will the kill bar indicate, a normal kill(normal arrow shot) or ultimate kill(Dragonstrike)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the arrow fired by Hanzo to activate his ultimate can kill enemy players.

The kill feed will indicate a kill with his ultimate as shown in the following video at around 12 seconds:

Comment: That ultimate kill symbol seems to be red. Weird.

Comment: The red symbol means that it was a critical hit, aka a headshot

Comment: That explains why I'm not familiar with it o_O

Comment: The arrow seems to continue moving through the enemy. Theoretically, does that mean the arrow could make a double-kill?

Comment: I will give it a try. My guess is that there is only one projectile that can actually hit enemies and the rest of it is just for show.